# HTML <select>, not <select multiple>: behavior when more than one option is selected

Tags: html, cross-browser

In [this simple jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/facxjgrv/) (code below), I have a regular `<select>`, not a `<select multiple>`, with two options having the `selected` attribute. In Chrome 39, I see "d" selected. Apparently the behavior is to select the last of the "selected" options, which seems logical. **Is this a behavior I can count on across browsers?**

```
<select>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b" selected>b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d" selected>d</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why not remove the second `selected` attribute? I don't think this behavior is defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A select element whose multiple attribute is not specified must not
>   have more than one descendant option element with its selected
>   attribute set.

source [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-option-selected)

So it's not valid HTML and therefore the browsers' behavior is not predictable. If you've create these selected options via Javascript, you should maybe handle your desired behavior via JS as well.

Comment: OK, I thought maybe I could take a shortcut. I've added server logic that will avoid this situation. Thanks.